# how to set maximum number of connection retries with Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a scenario where my rabbit mq instance is not always available and would like to set the maximum number of times a connection retry happens, Is this possible with amqp?

Example,

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
  CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
  factory.setUri("amqprl//");
  factory ../ try uri connection for 4 times max then fail if still no connection
  return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message producers will only try to create a connection when you send a message.

Message consumers (container factories) will retry indefinitely.

You can add a `ConnectionListener` to the connection factory and `stop()` the listener containers after some number of failures.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ConnectionListener {

    /**
     * Called when a new connection is established.
     * @param connection the connection.
     */
    void onCreate(Connection connection);

    /**
     * Called when a connection is closed.
     * @param connection the connection.
     * @see #onShutDown(ShutdownSignalException)
     */
    default void onClose(Connection connection) {
    }

    /**
     * Called when a connection is force closed.
     * @param signal the shut down signal.
     * @since 2.0
     */
    default void onShutDown(ShutdownSignalException signal) {
    }

    /**
     * Called when a connection couldn't be established.
     * @param exception the exception thrown.
     * @since 2.2.17
     */
    default void onFailed(Exception exception) {
    }

}
```